# Parse Server AWS Latency

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, parse-server

I have migrated my iOS app to AWS from Parse and have a few problems.

1. I am using Elastic Beanstalk and running a t2.small instance. Whenever I first deployed Parse Server, my application worked flawlessly. However after a random amount of time, the latency spikes up to 60 seconds or more, but it seems to never return any information even after waiting 60 seconds.  It will stay that high until I restart the server, and then it repeats.
2. Whenever the app is working after a fresh server restart, I am unable to delete any objects. I can post new objects, but when I try to delete, it says "Object Not Found." I first thought it could be an ACL problem, but the app worked fine before the migration.

I did not post any code because I don't think any code is the real issue considering my app worked perfectly before the conversion to AWS. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem with the 1st part of your question could be with CPU credits.Your instance could be running out of cpu credits.. check the CPUCreditUsage and CPUCreditBalance metrics for your server..here is the link to aws documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html.

Comment: Thats not the problem, I am currently the only one using the server and the CPU utilization is very low. @Shibashis

Comment: Re: Latency: One thing you should try is eliminating the MongoDB instance and just query the server to make sure it is responding in a timely manner like doing a GET on http://<your-domain>/parse/serverinfo. Re: Delete Object: Object Not Found will only respond if the call authenticated correctly so the permissions appear to be correct. Can you do a GET on the same object and it returns a value? My guess is that a GET will respond with Object not found as well.